# Throw an exception in one solution and catch it in another solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i'm having two project solutions, one for WebService and another for WebApplication.i came across a situation that i have to throw an exception(if occurs) in WebService project and catch it inside my WebApplication method calling the WebService's method.how can i achieve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an exception from a web service to a client is not advisable. A better approach would be to catch the exception in your web service and write it into your response object that you return to the client.

The client can then check whether the response contains an exception and do what ever you require.

Comment: :so if i'm returning `Model` object, i need to modify it to add a field in order to hold the `Exception` occured..

Comment: I would create a new custom class that has one property for your Model object and another for exception(s).